# My loop of GET requests with HttpClient falls into a mysterious flurry of AggregateExceptions

Tags: c#, multithreading, http

I'm new to this language, new to HttpClient, and bad with multithreading, so try to bear with me. I have a Windows Forms application that allows a user to input an ID. When they press Start, it will begin repeatedly making requests to a certain website's web API (until they press Stop), incrementing the ID by 1 each time. The ID is included with the requests; it makes the site return a JSON table of a virtual object associated with that ID. Thousands of these objects are uploaded to the site per minute.

Here is the method I am using to make the requests:

```
private async Task<string> GetResponseText(HttpClient client, string address)
{
        return await client.GetStringAsync(address);
}
```

So in the part of my code where I handle what happens when the program is going to start scanning, I first create a new HttpClient, like this:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
```

Then I create a brand new thread and start looping:

```
System.Threading.Thread scanThread = new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
{
    while (scanning)
    {
        string assetUrl = "https://api.example.com/blah?id=" + assetId.ToString();
        string response = GetResponseText(client, assetUrl).Result;
        dynamic assetJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response);
        if (assetJson != null)
        {
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                try
                {
                    // omitted lots of irrelevant stuff
                    assetId += 1;
                }
                catch (RuntimeBinderException)
                {
                    // this probably means the ID doesn't exist yet so I do nothing
                }
            });
        }
    }
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Abort();
});
scanThread.IsBackground = true;
scanThread.Start();
```

The first time I ran that, it worked fine. It succeeded with every single ID, and it went at least 5 or 10 requests per second. There were no weird exceptions or issues behind the scenes or anything like that. But then, out of the blue, after maybe a hundred or two requests, I got my first problem:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.AggregateException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
An unhandled exception of type 'System.AggregateException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: One or more errors occurred.
```

The stack trace narrowed down the problem to this line:

```
string response = GetResponseText(client, assetUrl).Result;
```

"That's okay," I thought to myself. I didn't know what was wrong, so I set up a try/catch block for that line. And this is the part that really makes me scratch my head.

With a try/catch in place, as soon as this error hits, it simply keeps happening over and over for the entire loop. It never recovers or continues normally. And there are two ways to fix it, the second of which is the weirdest:

1) Simply close the program and open it again

2) Stop scanning, wait patiently for about 6 lines to appear in Visual Studio's debug output about threads exiting, then start scanning again

That second scenario I feel like is a clue about why this is happening, but I'm not good enough to figure it out. What's happening? And why does waiting for some threads to close (whatever they are to begin with) fix the problem? Can I just get rid of those manually every time the loop runs?

Comment: Please try the same approach using the main thread. So delete your thread and pass the while loop directly in your form. Now at the end of your loop add Application.DoEvents(); So you can react and click stop button or sth. That's not the solution but if it helps you now it's just your threading which causes this issues.

Comment: Drill into the AggregateExceptions and find out what the inner exceptions are

Comment: @Sebi Application.DoEvents() stopped the entire application from responding, even when placed inside the while loop for some reason

Comment: @AntP I'm not sure how to do that

Comment: @Autumn drop a breakpoint in when you catch the exceptions and inspect the `InnerExceptions` property.

Comment: @AntP There is an InnerException property, which gives this:
    System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: 400 usually indicates that the target server has decided that your request is invalid (but they could return a 400 for any reason) - can you make the requests you're making manually with success? Could the service be rate limiting you?

Comment: @Autumn Maybe you using Id's which make the Url invalid? Because 400 means your Webserver can't interprete your url to valid http code.

Comment: @AntP I've tried making the request manually in my web browser, even when the program hits that wall of errors, and it works perfectly. It also recovers consistently when I close/open the program (or when I stop scanning, wait for those threads to exit, then start again)

Comment: @Sebi when the ID doesn't exist, the site returns a JSON table with an "error" value that describes the error. I've verified that I'm able to handle that properly, and it's different than the errors I'm getting.

Comment: @Autumn ok maybe the server limit the access. Often you need accesstokens if you want more then x operations in n minutes.

Comment: @Sebi I've verified that isn't happening. I run the program until it hits the errors, and then as the errors are still flooding in, I manually connect to the site with the same IP address with no issue. And no matter how quickly I close/open the program again, doing so always fixes it. If I simply stop scanning and wait for a bunch messages to appear in the console about threads exiting, then I start scanning again, the issue goes away, which I don't understand

Comment: I'd also like to understand why you're spinning up a thread to make a blocking call on an async HTTP request.

Comment: @AntP it's inside a form's button click event. Click it once and the loop starts, click it again and a bool changes and the loop dies. The while loop would freeze the program if I didn't make a new thread.

Comment: @Autumn i think antP means why you don't await your async Method GetResponseText.

Comment: @Autumn you are making asynchronous HTTP requests - use async all the way up and ditch the thread (or at least move the HTTP request outside of the background thread and make that part async).

Comment: Other than that I'm not sure what to suggest - debug and make sure the failing requests are what you expect, look to see if there is a body in the response that indicates what the problem was. The request is clearly reaching the target and receiving a response so it seems like your problem might be specific to this particular API.

Comment: @Sebi I was doing that before, I don't know why I changed it

Comment: @AntP I can't ditch the thread btw, since there's an infinite while loop. In the main thread that prevents the form from continuing with its event stuff. I need to be able to click the button again later to end the loop

Comment: @AntP Okay, thank you lots for the help you've given

Comment: @Autumn maybe use Task Library for threading is better way. So instead of your Threading you can use the while loop inside a task like: var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { //Your Code }); Use a cancellationtoken to abort it. This is prefered way. Your Threading is oldschool way ;).

Comment: @Sebi Thanks, I didn't know about that library. I will look into it :p

Comment: @Autumn i will post you an example as answer and update it until we found your damn problem :D

Comment: @Sebi it's alright! I've given up on this problem for today. I appreciate all of your help though =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTTP-Statuscode 400 means that your Request is invalid. So you have to check your HTTP-Request in detail. Maybe the API allows just a limited number of access or sth.

Further i will give you some code example which is more modern:

```
   var ts = new CancellationTokenSource();
   CancellationToken ct = ts.Token;

    private void Start()
    {
       var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {

         var client = new HttpClient();
         while(true)
         {
            if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
               break;
            }

            string assetUrl = "https://api.example.com/blah?id=" + assetId;
            string response = await GetResponseText(client, assetUrl);
            dynamic assetJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response);

            if (assetJson != null)
            {
               assetId++;
            }
         }
       }, ct).ContinueWith(ex => Console.WriteLine(ex.Message), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
     }


     private void Stop()
     {
        ct.Cancel();
     }
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm very certain that the problem is with this particular API, and I'll look into it next time I can. And the modern code is helpful.

Comment: @Autumn Your welcome. Yes i think the api will be the problem too.